# Apache running as root vs. new user

Tags: apache

From the Apache documentation, I read that Apache needs to initially run as root to then switch to the user defined by the User directive to serve requests.

However, I also read, still from the Apache documentation, that the recommended  strategy is to create a new user and a new group specific for running the server.

This is a bit confusing for me. If Apache needs to run as root, why do I need a new user? Does it refer to the webmaster running the server? Because, otherwise, the two statements look a bit contradictory to me.

Answer (score 0):

Let me quote from your own question:

> I read that Apache needs to initially run as root to then switch to the user defined by the User directive to serve requests.

Correct.

So that implies there needs to be a different (not root) user account to switch to ...

> However, I also read, still from the Apache documentation, that the recommended strategy is to create a new user and a new group specific for running the server.

Again, correct.

The recommendation is to create a user and group specifically for Apache rather than using some existing user / group.

No contradiction so far.

> If Apache needs to run as root, why do I need a new user?

Apache needs to **start** as root.

Then it needs to **switch** to a different user.

Why?

1. It needs to start as root, because some of the initial setup can only be performed while the process has elevated privileges.
2. It needs to change to a different account because it is **unsafe** to continue running with elevated privileges.  Why?  because if  hackers can find an exploit in the Apache process running as root, then they have achieved a root compromise.  (That's a hack of the worst kind ...)

In short, there is no contradiction.

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying. I got confused because here https://www.w3.org/Security/Faq/wwwsf3.html it is advised to create a new user for the web master and a new group for the HTML authors. Therefore the www user mentioned here IS NOT the user to be created specifically for Apache? Or is it? That is my doubt.